# Pass variable to merge_range in xlswriter python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

My goal is to merge columns from `S` upto a certain column based on the length of list. How can I pass that variable to `merge_range`?

```
worksheet.merge_range('S1:' + 'here i should pass the length of list into 2', '', custom_format)
```

I want to merge from `S` to twice the number of columns as the length of `my_list`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Columns are indexed using letters instead of numbers so you can either try to calculate the letter with an expression like

```
f"S1:{chr(ord('S') + len(data) - 1)}1"
```

**Or, even better, you can [use index notation instead of letter notation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html)**. This also prevents issues if you go past column `Z`:

```
# S is the 19th letter of the alphabet
worksheet.merge_range(0, 18, 0, 18 + len(data) - 1, 
                     'Merged Cells', merge_format)
```

Comment: My code merges a number of columns equal to the length of the list, for your use case you will have to do `2 * len(data)`

Comment: I'm the author of XlsxWriter and using the numeric range, as shown in this example, is the right way to do this. This is also shown in the [merge_range()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-merge-range) docs.